# How do I get the current URL of my script using PHP?

Tags: php, url

How do I get the current URL of my script using PHP?

Answer (score 32):

Please see [PHP Get Current URL](http://www.bradino.com/php/get-current-url/):

> Sometimes it is not as straightforward
>   as one may think to get the current
>   url to use it inside your application.
>   Here is a snippet that I use to fetch
>   the current URL and use it in a
>   script. The current url (whether http
>   or https) is now a local variable that
>   you can do with as you please.

```
$url = "http".(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?"s":"").
"://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

> Note: You should groom this value before using in anything sensitive, like a sql query.

Comment: server port is missing..

Comment: if you use rewrite to add variables after the script, like /x.php/123/456 then using REQUEST_URI will include those parameters.
SCRIPT_NAME might be better.

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 6):

For www.example.com/files/script.php

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`
 = **/files/script.php**

and if you want the current directory url:

`dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])` = **/files**

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to know the script name on your server, then..**

```
$file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
echo $file;
```

$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] will give you the current executed script path, which related on your server not on the browser's url.

Answer (score 2):

Whe you need info like this its often convenient to look at the output of phpinfo() and then read the docs on those items that seems good.

Keep in mind that some of them might be correct on your server, but slightly different on others.. Depending on os, http server etc.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you were accessing 
[How do I get the current URL of my script using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871770/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-of-my-script-using-php) 
then 
**echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];** // This will return u the hostname that is:- 
**stackoverflow.com/**
and 
**echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];** // It will return only the file name from current url
will return below 
**"/questions/1871770/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-of-my-script-using-php"**
 and not the hostname.

Comment: yes... PHP_SELF would only return the file... and not the other parameters.. and if one needs full path then he has to use "REQUEST_URI", and i have edited my answer..

Comment: not to mention that PHP_SELF is vulnerable to XSS.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi this is the solution of your problem**

//fetch page url by this

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "$url<br />";
```

//it will print

//fetch host by this

```
$host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo "$host<br />";
```

//you can fetch full url by this

```
$fullurl="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $fullurl;
```